# Getting file from Amazon s3 encrypted based on user

Tags: encryption, file-encryption, amazon-s3

I am storing my files on Amazon S3. My problem is that whenever a user asks for a file I want to generate an encryption key (user specific key) and encrypt the file and send it to him.

So basically I want to direct S3 server that I want this file with this key, it generates the url for me, I pass the url to the user and when the user hits this url he/she gets the file encrypted with my key.

I read about the encryption schemes on the S3 docs but couldn't find a way of doing this. All I got is that I can store file with encryption key and to retrieve it back I have to provide the encryption key to S3.

Is there a way of achieving this with S3?

Comment: I think you need an instance (or docker instance) to do this, which reads the file, encrypts it, etc.

Comment: @SPRBRN can you please point me how is it going to help me achieve user specific encryption

Comment: No I can't. You need a web application for that. It should be programmed or maybe you can find an app that can do that. This is just my understanding of S3, and AFAIK it's just a big fileserver, and programs run elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't.

S3's encryption services are for the data at rest *inside*, not outside, S3.